# Pegar valor json

Tags: php, json

O servidor contem um arquivo.txt  (http://192.168.27.3/lista.txt)  com as seguintes
informacoes:

```
[
  {
    "Nome": "Hemerson",
    "data": "05/11",

  },
  {
    "Nome": "Hemerson",
    "data": "06/11",

  }
]
```

estou querendo pegar a informação do ultimo nome e data gostaria de exibir em uma pagina assim:

http://192.168.27.3/api/create_post/?nome=Hemerson&data=05/11

dessa forma consigo mandar para meu banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema consiste no fato que seu `json` salvo no documento de texto tem uma sintaxe incorreta ou seja, não é um `json` valido.

Não sei como voçê salva em texto mas após cada objeto e antes de fechá-los voçê colocou uma virgula, ela esta errada por isso invalida seu documento como `json` se puder corrigir isto, um exemplo funcional para o que quer seria algo assim:

### file.txt

```
 [ { "Nome": "Hemerson", "data": "05/11"

 }, { "Nome": "Hemerson", "data": "06/11"

 } ]
```

### teste.php

```
<?php
    // leia o arquivo
    $file = file_get_contents('file.txt');    

    // decodifique em array associativo para poder pegar a ultima posição
    $decode = json_decode($file, true);

    // pegue a ultima posição
    $ultimo = end($decode);

    // acesse o valor pela chave correspondente exemplo "data"
    echo $ultimo['data'];

    // isso ira imprimir: 06/11
```

Comment: Ola Lauro deu certo  a decodificacao  so mais uma duvida se eu quiser pegar  o inicio em vez da ultima posicao como que seria coloquei assim mais nao deu certo $ultimo = start($decode);

Comment: Ola amigos resolvido  no lugar de $ultimo = end($decode); seria isso : $ultimo = reset ($decode);